Badge tracker on redesigned home page tracks the wrong one
On my profile page, I have manually selected which badge to track. Alas, the badge tracker on the obnoxious redesigned home page tracks whichever one Stack Overflow thought should be the default.
This seems like a silly omission (and another good reason to never do this sort of thing again).

I see I have one close vote for "needs details or clarity". I'm not sure what details the close voter wants; I notice that the badge help on [SO] doesn't explain this, but https://stackoverflowteams.help/en/articles/8814347-badges explains how you can choose which badge is being tracked on your profile.

I don't seem to have this problem. I can select the badge being tracked both from the new widget and also from the activity tab of the profile page.

@PeterJames If you select a different badge on your profile page, is that reflected on the home page? I have manually selected a gold topic badge to be tracked for me way before this change, but the home page insists on tracking the Epic tag.

@tripleee Yes, exactly. I am tracking Copy Editor on the BADGES widget at the moment and I can see this in both places.

@tripleee My next tag badge on the REPUTATION widget on the activity tab is HTML, but I can't see that anywhere else (I believe)

This is very clear. (Uno Reverse:) @close-voter, would you provide more details on why you think this question is unclear?
